# Looking for database to store multiple mapping dictionary

Tags: database

I have multiple excel sheet, which used to store statistical tables (around 10 stables, 2000x4 each) and use these tables to compute the formula. I am now using Python, thinking should I store these table into multiple nested dictionaries variable in Python to map the values during calculation or having a database to store these tables instead, if database is used, which database is suggested?

Comment: Hello, this question lacks any sort of details. Store for what purpose? Storing alone can be done in few different **types** of DB, including relational, noSQL, graph, etc.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL, MariaDB or PostgreSQL.

Choose the one you want.

You can also use SQL Server for free till 10Gb of data or use the Developer Edition with full features.